# Регулярные выражения PHP и пробелы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой вот текст в переменной в этом тексте пробелы, табуляции, переводы строк где попало
ставлю в регулярку \s он находит с пробелами, табуляциями без них уже не находит пишу \S|\s что-то типа `<li>\s|\S(?:Дата|Форма):\s|\S<span> \s|\S(.*)\s|\S<\/span>\s|\S` ищет пробелы переводы строк. Как можно сказать регулярке чтоб искал иключая все пробелы, табуляции, переводы строк?

```
<ul>
            <li>
                    Дата:

                <span> 2019 </span>
                </li>

                <li>Форма:<span> Красная </span>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

Comment: ни одного ответа на ваш вопрос, отмеченного вами как решение - вам трудно ткнуть на галку?

Comment: Галку? аххаха, думал это только модераторы могут делать

Comment: "_Как можно сказать регулярке чтоб искал иключая все пробелы, табуляции, переводы строк?_" - а что искать нужно?

Comment: <li>(?:Дата|Форма):<span> (.*)<\/span>

Comment: Искать и записывать в массив место где (.*)

Comment: т.е. то, что в контейнере `<span></span>` ?

Comment: То есть да искать то, что в контейнере span

Comment: `<span>(.+?)</span>`

Comment: А как сказать регулярному выражения, что перед span может быть перевод строки, табуляция пробел, а может и не быть?

Comment: Вот так _(и модификатор s в конце шаблона обязателен)_ : `'~\s*<span>(.+?)</span>~s'`

Comment: а фишка то в чём? пробел может быть и до span'a, перед li и до li может быть и перевод строки может быть не только пробел

Comment: фишка в том, что последовательность символов `\s` представляет собой символьный класс пробельных символов _(пробелы, переносы, табуляция)_. А модификатор `s` даёт соответствие точки "." любому символу.

Comment: Что вы делаете? У вас HTML-код, зачем вы вообще решили использовать регулярные выражения, которые с HTML "не дружат"? Каков желаемый результат?

Comment: Мне нужно с большого HTML кода достать данные. Просто я не знаю больше ничего, как достать данные с помощью регулярных выражений. Эдуард, https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/15032 нашёл работает. перевод строки https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/15033 уже не работает

Answer (score -1):

1. Не `\s|\S`, а `(\s|\S)`.
2. Пробел там явно не один, так что `(\s|\S)+` или `(\s|\S)*`.
3. Остальное не читал.

Comment: Хуже `(\s|\S)*` только `(.|\r|\n)*?`. **Никогда** не предлагайте и не используйте этого. Есть отличный шаблон, который нахдит любой символ - `.` вкупе с модификатором `s`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 1. Не везде есть модификатор `s`. 2. Никто не мешает тебе написать собственный ответ. 3. В вопросе есть явная ошибка и я её исправил. 4. Есть минимум один редактор, которому для корректной замены требуется `[\s\S\r\n]*`.

Comment: Это вопрос о PHP. Одну исправили, одну добавили.